# what is the reason behind getting the "invalid use of void expression" error in C?

Tags: c, expression, void, function-call, function-declaration

I have this piece of C code here :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
void message();
int main()
{
    message(message());
    return 0;
}
void message()
{
    printf("hello\n");
}
```

The compiler throws an error message reading " Invalid use of void expression" for the statement block "message(message))".

I expected the output to be two times the printf() statement as according to me, the statement message(message()); indicates that once the inner function call executes and the control returns to main and after that again the outer call executes. However I am getting the error message "Invalid use of void expression" error here.

I have read some explanations but still i'm unable to understand.

Comment: What _"inner function"_? You try to pass a function result to a function which has neither return type, nor parameters defined.

Comment: Why did you write it this way? This should be two statements calling `message();` instead.

Comment: `void message()` does not return any value, and you can't use a non-existent value as a function argument.

Comment: This code is actually from a c exercise module. It was written this way under the heading "find the error if any".

Comment: @Shivangi it seems you've found the error.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of the function message is void

```
void message();
```

So calling the function passing an argument of the incomplete type void invokes an error.

```
message(message());
```

If you want to call the function twice then write

```
message(); 
message();
```

or as one expression

```
message(), message();
```

Pay attention to that it is better to declare the function like

```
void message( void );
```

providing to the compiler the function prototype.

If you want to call the function specifying its argument as a call of it itself then the function should be declared and defined the following way

```
const char * message( const char *s )
{
    puts( s );

    return s;
}
```

and the function can be called like

```
message( message( "hello" ) );
```

Comment: Also note that `void message();` is *not* a prototype; it's an old-style K&R function declaration.